# Adding Cells to Dynamic UITableView DataSource | Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, model, datasource

I have a dynamic `UITableViewDataSource` that takes in a Model and a `UITableViewCell`

I would like to insert a different `UITableViewCell` into the 'nth' (10th for example) row... (for Google Ads)

### DATASOURCE

```
class ModelTableViewDataSource<Model, Cell: UITableViewCell>: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    typealias CellConfigurator = (Model, Cell) -> Void

    var models: [Model]

    private let reuseIdentifier: String
    private let cellConfigurator: CellConfigurator

    init(models: [Model], reuseIdentifier: String, cellConfigurator: @escaping CellConfigurator) {
        self.models = models
        self.reuseIdentifier = reuseIdentifier
        self.cellConfigurator = cellConfigurator
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return models.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let model = models[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) as! Cell
        cellConfigurator(model, cell)
        return cell
    }
}
```

I then add an extension for each Model

### MODEL

```
extension ModelTableViewDataSource where Model == SomeModel, Cell == SomeCell {
    static func make(for someModel: [SomeModel], reuseIdentifier: String = "Identifier") -> ModelTableViewDataSource {
        return ModelTableViewDataSource(models: someModel, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) { (someModel, someCell) in
            someCell.model = someModel
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to implement this keeping the re-usable functionality of the `UITableViewDataSource`

Comment: Do you want this ad in _each_ data source the `make` function creates, or only in a special one?

Comment: just in selected few.

Comment: Then I would create a different `make` function, that creates a subclass of `ModelTableViewDataSource` with the expected behavior.

Comment: Will try to build something out along those lines.  If you have any examples that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of this:

- create a subclass
- override `numberOfRowsInSection` to return number of rows + 1
- override `cellForRowAt` to handle the 10th row

  class ModelTableViewDataSourceWithAd: ModelTableViewDataSource {

  ```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection:section) + 1
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      if (indexPath.row == 9) {
          // return Google ad cell
      } else {
          return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt:indexPath)
      }
  }
  ```

  }

and then the creator:

```
extension ModelTableViewDataSource where Model == SomeModel, Cell == SomeCell {

// ...

    static func makeWithAd(for someModel: [SomeModel], reuseIdentifier: String = "Identifier") -> ModelTableViewDataSource {
        return ModelTableViewDataSourceWithAd(models: someModel, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) { (someModel, someCell) in
            someCell.model = someModel
        }
    }

}
```